# How to compare screen scraped data with file.

Tags: python, selenium, comparison, screen-scraping

I have created a screen scraping program using selenium, which prints out a few variables. I want to take the numbers it spits out and compare it to numbers in a text document. I am unsure on the process of going about this. What would be the best way to go about this. The text file will contain a 3 numbers which will be compared to 3 numbers that have been screen scraped.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
#The above is downloading the needed files for this code to work
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\ashabandha\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://signin.acellus.com/SignIn/index.html")
time.sleep(2)
username = driver.find_element_by_id("Name")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("Psswrd")
username.send_keys("my login")
password.send_keys("my password")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="loginform"]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/input""").click()
#The program has now signed in and is going to navigate to the progress tab
time.sleep(2)
driver.get("https://admin252.acellus.com/StudentFunctions/progress.html?ClassID=484")
time.sleep(2)
#now we are on the progress tab
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Object7069")
time.sleep(2)
for post in posts:
    print (post.text)
#this gives me the first class log
time.sleep(2)
driver.get("https://admin252.acellus.com/StudentFunctions/progress.html?ClassID=326")
#This gives me second class log
time.sleep(2)
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Object7069")
time.sleep(2)
for post in posts:
    print (post.text)
time.sleep(2)
driver.get("https://admin252.acellus.com/StudentFunctions/progress.html?ClassID=292")
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Object7069")
time.sleep(2)
for post in posts:
    print (post.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Save selenium output on a data structure, like list or dictionary, then open the file, extract the info you want to compare it to and do the algorithm or expression you wish to it: https://www.python.org/doc/
check out working with file.